# error: identifier "float3" is undefined; When running oclNbody demo on ATI card

Tags: compiler-errors, opencl, ati

I'm trying to run NVidia's OpenCL demo oclNbody.exe on ATI Radeo 4850 card and receive such errors:

> Build Log:
>   C:\DOCUME~1\DIMEDR~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\OCL27C.tmp.cl(33):
>   error: identifier
>
> ```
>       "float3" is undefined
> ```
>
> REAL3 bodyBodyInteraction(REAL3 ai,
>   REAL4 bi, REAL4 bj, REAL
>   softeningSquared)
>
> ^

And so on for all REAL3 datatype using. I have seen the [OpenCL specification 1.1](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/) and it clearly says that float3 is supported. I've tried to change REAL3 with float3 with no luck. I have the latest drivers for my card. Using Windows XP SP3 OS

How can I fix or work around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround:

- use float 4 instead of float3;
- #define ZERO4 {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} and use it instead ZERO3
- and decrease the number of workgroup to 64 (was 256)

and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

`float3` and other 3-component vector types were not part of the OpenCL 1.0 spec; they were added in the 1.1 revision. According to [AMD's driver compatibility page](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx), the Radeon HD 4800 cards only support OpenCL 1.0.

The fact that the compiler tried to interpret `float3` as an identifier shows that it is not a recognized type.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about 1.0. I must have missed that.